# How to reload a script's src

Tags: javascript, src

I have a script tag with an src, how can I reload the src with java script code, this is the code I have:

```
<script src='./script.php'>
<script>
function reload() {
  //the code to reload the src
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snippet:

```
<script>
        function reload() {
          var head= document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
          var script= document.createElement('script');
          script.src= './script.php';
          head.appendChild(script);
       }
       reload();
</script>
```

Comment: thanks it works do you know how to the get a var from it

Comment: You need to ask this in a different post with this piece of code :), if it worked, please mark the answer as correct.